# my app can't be open but can download when i publish a new version in google play after change sign with Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My app has two version in Google. The first work well, recently, I want to publish a new version,but i found that i forgot my upload sign ,so i regain it with Google Play App Signing. The new version can be downloaded but can't be open.it make me so dispirited.

that's null

for google style

> 12-09 16:07:23.589 391-391/? V/WLAN_PSA: NL MSG, PID: 391
>   12-09 16:07:23.869 320-320/? I/SurfaceFlinger: FPS: 2
>   12-09 16:07:23.869 3504-3504/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController: onSignalStrengthsChanged received on slotId :0signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -76 -7 290 2147483647 2147483647 gsm|lte level=5 cdmdlevel=0 evdolevel=0
>   12-09 16:07:24.219 19899-19899/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
>   12-09 16:07:25.219 19899-19899/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
>   12-09 16:07:25.229 320-320/? I/SurfaceFlinger: FPS: 3
>   12-09 16:07:26.219 19899-19899/? I/ServiceManager: Waiting for service AtCmdFwd...
>   12-09 16:07:26.249 320-320/? I/SurfaceFlinger: FPS: 2

my app can work 

upload my sign in google

Comment: 12-09 16:09:16.869 4038-4038/? D/WtProcessStrategy: do trim { PackageName :android Pid: 2385 Uid: 1000 Start by: unknown Score:50 Old score:50 state:0 mBackgroundTimeInMillis:1512804522076 WakelockCount:0 wakelogsize:0  ActivityDestroied:false Activity size: 0 PackageInfo:{WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:android uid:1000 uiMemoryThresold:0 nonUiMemoryThresold:0 Flag:-2147221248,0x80040100 [,APP_SYSTEM] Type:0[] } tasknum:-1}

Comment: my phone can not run the appalication so i can't catch the logcat ,maybe this is the log which the app downloaded in my phone

Comment: What does "can't open" actually mean? Any error messages?

Comment: @Henry  no any messages. just can't start .I click the app but has no response